# Spring Boot YAML configuration for a list of strings

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I am trying to load an array of strings from the `application.yml` file. This is the config:

```yaml
ignore:
    filenames:
        - .DS_Store
        - .hg
```

This is the class fragment:

```java
@Value("${ignore.filenames}")
private List<String> igonoredFileNames = new ArrayList<>();
```

There are other configurations in the same class that loads just fine. There are no tabs in my YAML file. Still, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'ignore.filenames' in string value "${ignore.filenames}"
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

My *guess* is, that the `@Value` can not cope with "complex" types.  You can go with a prop class like this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties('ignore')
class IgnoreSettings {
    List<String> filenames
}
```

**Please note:** This code is *Groovy* - **not Java** - to keep the example short!  See the comments for tips how to adopt.

See the complete example https://github.com/christoph-frick/so-springboot-yaml-string-list

Comment: You can bind a comma-separated with `@Value` (as long as a converter is registered, which it will be in Spring Boot I think).

Comment: @Bahadır i tried this code here and it works.  `@ComponentScan` and friends picks this up?

Comment: It is picking up string settings but not List<String> settings

Comment: you are sure, that `@ConfigProperties('NAME')` is the root in your config.yaml, that your `List<String> LIST` is the same name as the key in the config.yaml and there is a valid list of strings in the yaml?  as i said: i tried above code with SB 1.1.8 and it worked. i will later put this on a gist

Comment: Even with an example that simple, it does not retrieve a String list from my YAML config file. it's a bit omg and driving me crazy. (SpringBoot 1.2.6)

Comment: @StijnVanBael are you sure, that this was the only change?  From the `@Configuration` docs: > {@code @Configuration} is meta-annotated with {@link Component @Component}, therefore
 {@code @Configuration} classes are candidates for component scanning ...

Comment: There must also be a getter defined for the property.

Comment: This looks like it is a limitation with the spring boot processes that annotation - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/501

Comment: This approach seems to have broken for me starting with dependencies on Spring Cloud Dependencies Hoxton SR5 vs SR4. I had to initialize the list now.

Answer (score 216):

use comma separated values in application.yml

```
ignoreFilenames: .DS_Store, .hg
```

java code for access

```
@Value("${ignoreFilenames}")    
String[] ignoreFilenames
```

It is working ;)

Comment: I was hoping this would work in Dropwizard too :'(  thanks though!

Comment: In my own tests, this is equivalent to ".DS_Store, .hg" but not ".DS_Store", ".hg" - the latter fails with "org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserException: while parsing a block mapping". So what you're actually doing here is providing the property as a single comma-separated string (which Spring then splits into an array or list) instead of a YAML array. This "works" but doesn't answer the original question. I have yet to find a way to parse a YAML array in a @Value annotated bean property.

Comment: `List<String>` rather than `String[]` works as well

Comment: Create separate property config class and use List<String> instead of String[]. And in yml file configure like ignore:
    filenames:
        - .DS_Store
        - .hg

Answer (score 72):

From the Spring Boot docs:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config (3.0.x)
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config (2.7.x)

YAML lists are represented as property keys with [index] dereferencers, for example this YAML:

```
my:
   servers:
       - dev.bar.com
       - foo.bar.com
```

Would be transformed into these properties:

```
my.servers[0]=dev.bar.com
my.servers[1]=foo.bar.com
```

To bind to properties like that using the Spring DataBinder utilities (which is what `@ConfigurationProperties` does) you need to have a property in the target bean of type `java.util.List` and you either need to provide a setter, or initialize it with a mutable value, e.g. this will bind to the properties above.  Here is what the question's code would look like.

(**Note**: The example below only works on Spring Boot 3.0 and greater. Previous versions require the `@ConstructorBinding` annotation to be present to not throw exceptions when this object is being constructed.)

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="ignore")
//@ConstructorBinding // uncomment if using Spring Boot 2.x.
public class Filenames {

    private List<String> ignoredFilenames = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getFilenames() {
        return this.ignoredFilenames;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be working, BTW `getXxx()` is necessary for it to work, and must use a `List`, not `Set`.

Comment: In the yaml, the list of values for the ArrayList can be a comma delimited list. In my case, I have many values, so a compact list is cleaner than an item per line. So in the example, you can do servers: dev.bar.com, foo.bar.com

Comment: Could the yaml be loaded from a properties file like this: `servers: ${my.servers}`? To get `my.servers[0]` and `my.servers[1]` into the yaml? I'm trying to have stage dependent configurations

Answer (score 56):

In addition to [Ahmet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41462567/2065796) you can add line breaks to the coma separated string using `>` symbol.

**application.yml**:

```
ignoreFilenames: >
  .DS_Store, 
  .hg
```

**Java code**:

```
@Value("${ignoreFilenames}")    
String[] ignoreFilenames;
```

Comment: This works well as long as you don't have any more commas (,) in your strings.

Comment: This doesn't work to read properties as arraylist. It reads them as single String.

Answer (score 44):

In my case, this was a syntax issue in the .yml file. I had:

```java
@Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
public List<String> BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_LIST;
```

and the list in my .yml file:

```yaml
bootstrap-servers:
    - s1.company.com:9092
    - s2.company.com:9092
    - s3.company.com:9092
```

was not reading into the `@Value`-annotated field. When I changed the syntax in the .yml file to:

```yaml
bootstrap-servers: >
    s1.company.com:9092,
    s2.company.com:9092,
    s3.company.com:9092
```

it worked fine.

Comment: Trying this on spring-boot 1.5 this does not work. You need a colon after bootstrap-servers

Comment: Using spring boot 2.x, the list has a single element of all the values with space separated.

Comment: @Taugenichts You're correct a colon is missing.


    bootstrap-servers: >

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "syntax issue in the YAML file" – the syntax in the YAML is correct for a list of strings, just `@Value` can't cope with complex types.

Answer (score 19):

Well, the only thing I can make it work is like so:

```
servers: >
    dev.example.com,
    another.example.com

@Value("${servers}")
private String[] array;
```

And dont forget the @Configuration above your class....

Without the "," separation, no such luck...

Works too (boot 1.5.8 versie)

```
servers: 
       dev.example.com,
       another.example.com
```

Comment: I prefer the first version with > though. If you put comment (e.g. after every line) IDE (IntelliJ) won't highlight the comment it in the first case but highlights it in the second case. It seems like it is supported to put the comment in the second case but it is not. The parser fails in both cases if the comment is there (spring-boot 2.2.10).

Answer (score 14):

```
@Value("#{'${your.elements}'.split(',')}")  
private Set<String> stringSet;
```

yml file:

```
your:
 elements: element1, element2, element3
```

There is lot more you can play with spring spEL.

Comment: Unnecessary because Spring already does this split by comma by default!

Answer (score 11):

[Ahmet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41462567/2877155) provides on how to assign the comma separated values to String array.

To use the above configuration in different classes you might need to create getters/setters for this.. 
But if you would like to load this configuration once and keep using this as a bean with Autowired annotation, here is the how I accomplished:

In ConfigProvider.java

```
@Bean (name = "ignoreFileNames")
@ConfigurationProperties ( prefix = "ignore.filenames" )
public List<String> ignoreFileNames(){
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

In outside classes:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("ignoreFileNames")
private List<String> ignoreFileNames;
```

you can use the same list everywhere else by autowiring.

Comment: That works. In my case though the application failed, unless I add `@Configuration` at the beginning of the class in `ConfigProvider.java`. Otherwise i got **Source required a bean of type 'java.util.List' that could not be found.**

Answer (score 3):

Configuration in yaml file:

```yaml
ignore:
    filenames: >
        .DS_Store
        .hg
```

In spring component:

```
@Value("#{'${gnore.filenames}'.split(' ')}")
private List<String> igonoredFileNames;
```

This worked fine for me.

Answer (score -3):

```
@Value("${your.elements}")    
private String[] elements;
```

yml file:

```
your:
 elements: element1, element2, element3
```

Comment: How is this different form Ahmet's answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41462567/2065796

Comment: Answer already provided. Answering just for the sake of points doesn't add value