# Spring Boot YAML config and list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have to integrate a list in a YAML config file in Spring Boot, and don't see how to proceed.

I already saw other questions related : [Spring Boot yaml configuration for a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699385/spring-boot-yaml-configuration-for-a-list-of-strings)

And have the same issue.

I applied the solution and worked around, and found the solution a little tricky.

Is there a way to make lists work with the @Value ?

And if not now, is it expected in future ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would properties file format be simpler than YAML ?

Comment: It seems this has not been fixed in Spring and there are no plans to do: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/747

Comment: Too bad, because the way to make it works is very tricky. Maybe i'm going to make my list as String with comma, even if i think this is not a good way :/

Answer (score 3):

According to this documentation you can do a list in yaml.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml

YAML lists are represented as property keys with [index] dereferencers, for example this YAML:

```
my:
   servers:
       - dev.bar.com
       - foo.bar.com
```

Would be transformed into these properties:

```
my.servers[0]=dev.bar.com
my.servers[1]=foo.bar.com
```

To bind to properties like that using the Spring DataBinder utilities (which is what @ConfigurationProperties does) you need to have a property in the target bean of type java.util.List (or Set) and you either need to provide a setter, or initialize it with a mutable value, e.g. this will bind to the properties above

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
public class Config {

    private List<String> servers = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getServers() {
        return this.servers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6Scea1JdMg&t=9s
```

Please refer to the above link. Maybe it helps, shown how to read different data types in application.yml in the Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a related GitHub thread: [@Value annotation should be able to inject List from YAML properties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16381). The issue has been closed, and according to [a comment in a duplicate issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28018#issuecomment-1032424556), they're not considering implementing the support now. It will be reopened once they decide to work on it.

Until then, you can go the way described in @mark's answer, using `@ConfigurationProperties`, also mentioned on GitHub.