# Spring Boot: read list from yaml using @Value or @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-boot, yaml, snakeyaml

I want to read a list of hosts from a yaml file (application.yml), the file looks like this:

```
cors:
    hosts:
        allow: 
            - http://foo1/
            - http://foo2/
            - http://foo3/
```

(Example 1)

My class used defines the value like this:

```
@Value("${cors.hosts.allow}")   
List<String> allowedHosts;
```

But reading fails as Spring complains about this:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'cors.hosts.allow' in string value "${cors.hosts.allow}"

When I change the file like this the property can be read but naturally it does not contain the list but only one entry:

```
cors:
    hosts:
        allow: http://foo1, http://foo2, http://foo3
```

(I know that I could read the values as a single line and split them by `","` but I do not want to go for a workaround yet)

This does not work either (although I think this should be valid according to [snakeyamls docs](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation)):

```
cors:
    hosts:
        allow: !!seq [ "http://foo1", "http://foo2" ]
```

(Skipping the `!!seq` and just using the `[` / `]` is a failure too)

I read the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699385/spring-boot-yaml-configuration-for-a-list-of-strings) which involves using `@ConfigurationProperties` and transferred the example to Java and used it with the yaml file you see in Example1:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cors.hosts")
public class CorsConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @NotNull
    public List<String> allow;
...
```

When I run this I get this complaint:

> org.springframework.validation.BindException:
>   org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder$RelaxedBeanPropertyBindingResult:
>   1 errors Field error in object 'cors.hosts' on field 'allow': rejected
>   value [null]; codes [NotNull.cors.hosts.allow,NotNull.allow,NotNull];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [cors.hosts.allow,allow]; argumen ts []; default message
>   [allow]];

I searched for other means to have my CORS hosts configurable and found this [Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3052) but as this is not yet finished I can't use it as a solution.
All of this is done with Spring Boot 1.3 RC1

Comment: Seems like an unresolved Spring bug ([SPR-11759](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11759)).

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt I tried to switch to `@ConfigurationProperties` and unfortunately this does not work either.

Answer (score 10):

use comma separated values in application.yml

```
corsHostsAllow: http://foo1/, http://foo2/, http://foo3/
```

java code for access

```
@Value("${corsHostsAllow}")    
String[] corsHostsAllow
```

I tried and succeeded ;)

Comment: It is also works with list:

'@Value("${realtime.tokenPermissions}")
    private List<String> tokenPermissions;'

Comment: It did NOT worked for me! ... ir doesnt split the values it just load as a single valued list

Comment: you could also use List<String>. and without @Value (field name is enough)

Answer (score 9):

It's easy, the answer is in this [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-nested-properties) and also in [this one](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties)

So, you have a yaml like this:

```
cors:
    hosts:
        allow: 
            - http://foo1/
            - http://foo2/
            - http://foo3/
```

Then you first bind the data

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="cors.hosts")
public class AllowedHosts {
    private List<String> HostNames; //You can also bind more type-safe objects
}
```

Then in another component you just do

```
@Autowired
private AllowedHosts allowedHosts;
```

And you are done!

Comment: Worked for me! But I had to create my class as static otherwise I got beaninstantiationexception saying it was missing default construction.

Comment: Just a simple change - you need a getter so you can get at allowedHost in the component that has the Autowired instance of AllowedHosts.

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to read list from  properties like below way-

Properties-

```
cors.hosts.allow[0]=host-0
cors.hosts.allow[1]=host-1
```

Read property-

```
@ConfigurationProperties("cors.hosts")
public class ReadProperties {
    private List<String> allow;

    public List<String> getAllow() {
       return allow;
    }
    public void setAllow(List<String> allow) {
        this.allow = allow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comma separated value works for yaml. So it should be-
cors:
  hosts:
    allow: habuma-20, habuma-21

Comment: I would upvote this. It may not be appropriate for ths question but I stumbled across this answer and this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, But solved, give you my solution

```
exclude-url: >
  /management/logout,
  /management/user/login,
  /partner/logout,
  /partner/user/login
```

success in the version of Spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE

Comment: I guess this is more a string that is split over multiple lines and not a list

Answer (score 0):

Declare List of values in yml as shown below

`fruits: apple, banana`

Injection into Java code

```java
@Value("${fruits}")
private List<String> fruits;
```

Yml based list syntax is not recognized by spring-boot at least in spring 2.7.4 version

```yaml
fruits: 
  - apple
  - banana
```

`It says Could not resolve placeholder 'fruits' in value "${fruits}"`