# Loading a list of strings from application.yml into a component

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

After reading a couple of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369878/spring-boot-read-list-from-yaml-using-value-or-configurationproperties) on StackOverflow, I tried to implement it as recommended, but I am still not getting a string list in my `@Component`.

Here is my `application.yml` file

```yaml
appName:
    db:
        host: localhost
        username: userX
        password: passX
        driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    shipment:
        providers:
            supported:
                - one
                - two
```

And my `@Component` class is

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "appName.shipment.providers")
public class ProviderUtil {

    List<String> supported;

    /* This class has other util methods as well */
}
```

Here, I expect that `supported` would have a list of strings `one` and `two` but is `null`. Can someone help me understand what is happening here and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have spring-boot-configuration-processor dependency on your classpath?
Try to look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor)

And also change your bean from @Component to @Configuration

Comment: Yup, i have added it exactly the way it is mentioned in the docs. with `optional` value set to `true` and I used `component` because of this reponse >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699385/spring-boot-yaml-configuration-for-a-list-of-strings ... That being said, I have tried both with `configuration` and `component` but no luck

Comment: Try to share your code to see if we can help you somehow.

Comment: I figured out the issue. I hadn't provided the getters/setters. I had made the field public and i thought it would work

Answer (score 0):

I followed this post and added the getters and setters for the list. It worked out for me.

#### Code:

```java
@Service("testservice")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="es")
public class TestService {

    @Value("${url.endPoint}")
    private String endpointUrl;

    private List<String> scope;

    public List<String> getScope() {
        return scope;
    }

    public void setScope(List<String> scope) {
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Please don't write everything in code-blocks. Use normal markup for your text.