# Getting null values when using ConfigurationProperties on Spring boot

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to the Java world and Spring boot, and I'm trying to access some configuration values located in a YAML file through the `ConfigurationProperties` annotation.

But whenever I try to access a configuration value anywhere in a service, I get a null value.

Here's the `application.yml` file:

```
my_config:
  test: "plop"
```

Here's the `ValidationProperties` configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my_config")
public class ValidationProperties {

    @NotNull
    private String test;

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return this.test;
    }
}
```

A validator service that uses it:

```
@Service
public class MyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyConstraint, MyEntity> {

    @Autowired
    private ValidationProperties validationProperties;

    @Value("${my_config.test}")
    private String test;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MyEntity entity, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        System.out.println(this.test); // null value, why?
    }
}
```

I also added the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation in my main class.

I'm not sure which annotation is supposed to do what, but I'm obviously missing something here. Also, if I try to access the value from the getter of the configuration file, I get an exception:

```
System.out.println(this.validationProperties.getTest());
```

will get me `HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.`

Comment: This post may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369878/spring-boot-read-list-from-yaml-using-value-or-configurationproperties

Comment: did you include https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `@EnableConfigurationProperties(ValidationProperties.class)`
on your main application class or any other `@Configuration` class.

Also putting `@Component` annotation on ValidationProperties should work.

No need to inject value via `@Value` annotation, just access it via getter of injected `validationProperties` object

Answer (score 0):

I got this error running a JUnit test on a SpringBoot app, what I was missing is the annotation `@SpringBootTest`