# Injecting an array from a YML file into Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot project where I want an array of strings to be defined in my `application.yml` file. I want to use Spring to inject this array into a variable for use inside of one of my classes as below:

```
@Component
Class foo {
    @Value("${properties.ymlArray}")
    private ArrayList<String> fooArray;

    @Value("${properties.ymlArray[1]}")
    private String itemFromFooArray;
}
```

My YML file is as follows:

```
properties:
  ymlArray: [item1, item2, item3]
```

In the above example `itemFromFooArray` populates correctly, getting an item from the array, but I have not found the appropriate way to inject the entire array into a variable.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This topic help you: <br>
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699385/spring-boot-yaml-configuration-for-a-list-of-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699385/spring-boot-yaml-configuration-for-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("properties")
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyConfig {
  List<String> ymlArray;
}
```

`@ConfigurationProperties(<propName>)` specifies what property value in your `application.yml` to read.
You can Autowire this in your `foo` class to get access to those property values.

```
@Component
Class foo {
    @Autowired
     MyConfig myConfig;
}
```

`myConfig.getYmlArray()` will have the array with all three values.

Comment: What package do the Getter and Setter annotations come from? I was able to make it work by creating my own getter/setters but would like to be able to use the annotations.

Comment: @nsprenkle they most likely come from `Lombok` library to reduce boilerplate code