# Java application.properties and Kubernetes env variables. How to handle a list?

Tags: java, kubernetes, application.properties

I have application.properties with a list like so:

```
api.users[0].name=dsaass@fakeacc.com
api.users[0].password=123QWEasd
api.users[1].name=dsadsasa@fakeacc.com
api.users[1].password=123qweASD
```

Now I need a Kubernetes env var for production/dev/demo etc. My other variables are declared like this:

```
ftp.port=${FTP_PORT:22}
```

But how do I do it with a list?

Of course having users like this is not good practice and is temporary, just a proof of concept app.

Comment: (the answers for) [Environment variables for list in spring boot configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55106571/592355) might be helpful..

Comment: Also, you can try to mount configmap as file, check this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415913/whats-the-best-way-to-share-mount-one-file-into-a-pod) and [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#configmap).

Comment: Unfortunately I can not reconfigure the POD to use configMap :(

Comment: Why you can't use configmap? Do you have any restrictions? Your cluster is on local machine or cloud?

Comment: This is a cloud project, where many developers contribute. I can not make any changes to bitbucket-pipelines.yml

Comment: Could you please clarify, how it suppose to look like from inside the pod? It's not clear do you want to put all of them at the same time or use specific pair for each environment?

Comment: All of them at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Use configMap and secrets (--from-file ) and mount it to volume to be read or read it as an environment variable.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/

Comment: Helpful, but I can not reconfigure the POD to use configMap.