# How to read a variable number of @RequestMapping paths from properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-el

In Spring (Boot) I can externalize annotation values to application / environment properties using the `${...}` syntax:

```
@RequestMapping("${some.path.property}")
```

I can also map a controller to more than one path:

```
@RequestMapping("/one", "/two")
```

How do I combine the two? I would like to define a list of paths in my properties, either as comma-separated `/one, /two` or (preferably) as a list in my `application.yaml`:

```
some.path.property:
    - /one
    - /two
```

But how can I interpolate either kind of list into the annotation?

```
@RequestMapping(???)
```

---

Edit: I couldn't figure out how to read the entire list from YAML (maybe because it's turned into separate properties `some.path.property[0]`, `some.path.property[1]`... at YAML parse time?)

For the simpler case of a single CSV property, say:

```
some.csv.property: /one, /two
```

I can use a property substitution: `"${some.csv.property}"` or an explicit SpEL split: `"#{'${some.csv.property}'.split('[, ]+')}"` to convert it into an array, but in both cases it only work for `@Value` annotations. If I try it on `@RequestMapping`, I always end up with a single path.

---

Edit2: I can do this, where `--` is just a random string that is not a valid path, but it's super ugly:

```
@RequestMapping(
    "${some.path.property[0]:--}",
    "${some.path.property[1]:--}",
    "${some.path.property[2]:--}",
    "${some.path.property[3]:--}",
    "${some.path.property[4]:--}",
    "${some.path.property[5]:--}",
    "${some.path.property[6]:--}",
    "${some.path.property[7]:--}",
    "${some.path.property[8]:--}",
    "${some.path.property[9]:--}"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have You tried this?:

```
some:
  path:
    property: /one, /two
```

And then

```
@RequestMapping("${some.path.property}")
```

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41462567/7425783 it should work fine

Comment: Yes, I tried it (with and without a space after the comma) and it doesn't work. I'm on the latest Spring Boot 2.1.2

Comment: To expand, I tried setting an array from a CSV property and it works: `@Value("${some.csv.property}") String[] myValue;` but when I use the same property for an annotation itself, it is not split on commas, but is just taken as a single string: `@RequestMapping("${some.csv.property}")` sets a single path with value `"/one, /two"`

Comment: I figured out how to use SpEL to explicitly split a string into an array: `"#{'${some.csv.property}'.split('[, ]+')}"` but again, it works for `@Value` but not for `@RequestMapping`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a yaml property file (don't repeat your self principle :) ), you can do it like so:

```
some:
  path:
    property:
      one: /path1
      two: /path2
```

If you're using @GetMapping ( or @RequestMapping ) you can do it like this in your controller :

```
@GetMapping(value={"${some.path.property.one}", "${some.path.property.two}"})
```

And here is the log

```
 Mapped "{[/path1 || /path2],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.zero.SimpleController> com.zero.SimpleController.hello()
```

Comment: Yes, I have `application.yaml`. I can do that, but then I cannot change the **number** of paths from the config file

Comment: I think @Michal solution is more suited for your case, the only issue is that you can't inherit path from super class ( if you have an `AbstractController` with `RequestMapping("/api/v1" )` and your `SimpleController extends AbstractController`), in this case either you set the full path in your property file or prefix/suffix the value from property file with another part of the complete path

Comment: In my case don't have the issue of inheriting the path from a super class. But @Michal's solution is simply not working. I can use it to initialize an array: `@Value("${some.csv.property}") String[] myValue;` but not an annotation value itself. In that case the string is not split into an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try create `HandlerMapping` to add urls, here is just an example to use `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`

```
@RestController
public class WelcomeController {

    public String ping() {
        return "pong";
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class StackOverflowApplication {

    @Autowired
    WelcomeController welcomeController;

    @Value("${paths}")
    List<String> paths;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StackOverflowApplication.class, args);
    }



    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        final Method getUser = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(WelcomeController.class, "ping");
        final HandlerMethod handlerMethod = new HandlerMethod(welcomeController, getUser);
        for (String path : paths) {
            map.put(path, handlerMethod);
        }
        simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setUrlMap(map);
        simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);

        return simpleUrlHandlerMapping;
    }


}
```

yml file

```
paths: ping, ping1, ping2, ping3
```

Here is the code in [github](https://github.com/chao-luo/stackoverflow/tree/Q55122525)

Comment: Yes, that's certainly an option. A bit heavy handed though.

Comment: @Tobia Did you manage to solve this?  I am looking to do the same thing and am relying on reading the values from properties but have so far been unsuccessful.

Comment: @ceepan No, I never solved it. Additionally, since 2019 many things have changed. I threw Java and Spring to the bin and I'm using PHP again.