# @Value with List in Kotlin from YAML

Tags: spring, kotlin, yaml

I am trying to initialise a list of properties from a YAML file in a Spring Boot project with Kotlin.

It works fine for a normal string, but fails when I try to init a List with the following error:

```
Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'foo.bars' in value "${foo.bars}"
```

The Kotlin code has the following constructor argument

```
@Value("\${foo.bars}")
val foobars: List<String>
```

the yaml file has the following values:

```
foo:
  bars:
  - test1
  - test2
```

Do I need to do something different between Lists and normal Strings?

Comment: Have you tried with Array instead of List?

Comment: tried it now, got the same error: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'foo.bars' in value "${foo.bars}""

Comment: Have you defined the property value? It seems to me that the problem is that Spring can't find the property.

Comment: looks like the syntax I was using was wrong or not supported, I used what you see in the post, but it seems a comma separated list works out.

Comment: There is work-around that works in Kotlin as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26700938/4395348

Answer (score 2):

Solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26700938/4395348) can be changed a bit for Kotlin:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("foo")
class FooBarsProperties {
  lateinit var bars: List<String>
}
```

Simply inject **FooBarsProperties** where you need it. Don't forget to add **@EnableConfigurationProperties** to some of your configuration classes.