# Reading String array data from properties.yml file in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services

I have to read a few string array variables from properties file of my spring-boot project.I have already created a class with getter and setter methods for the arrays.I don't know how to get the values of those string array variables from the property.yml file using java 1.8

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41462567/3560866

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using @Value

In your `.yaml`:

```
myPropertiesList: item1, item2
```

or

```
myPropertiesList: >
  item1, 
  item2
```

In your Java class:

```
@Value("${myPropertiesList}")    
String[] myPropertiesArray;
```

or in SpringBoot2:

```
@Value("${myPropertiesList}")
List<String> myPropertiesList;
```

### Using @ConfigurationProperties

In your `.yaml`:

```
myPrefix.myPropertiesList: item1, item2
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myPrefix")
public class ConfigProperties {
    private List<String> myPropertiesList;
}
```

and add the following to your SpringBoot configuration:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfigProperties.class)
```

Comment: That worked @babyburger in my yaml i was putting it as [a,b]