# How to read list values from properties file

Tags: java, spring, annotations

application.yml file

```
countries:['India','USA']
```

How to read this countries parameters in Java with `@Value` annotation?

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699385/spring-boot-yaml-configuration-for-a-list-of-strings/26700938

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot yaml configuration for a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699385/spring-boot-yaml-configuration-for-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 0):

use comma separated values in application.yml

`countries: India, USA`

java code for access

`@Value("${countries}")`
`String[] countries`

Comment: Yes..i know that...but unfortunately my requirement is like this

Answer (score 0):

First Approach:

Your YAML list should look like this:

```
acme:
  countries:
    - India
    - USA
```

Then add the following annotation to your Country class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "acme")
public class Country {

    private List<String> countries = new ArrayList<>();

   //constructor, getter/setter etc.

}
```

Lastly you need to add another annotation to your SpringBootApplication app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(Country.class)
```

Finally get the countries by autowiring the Country class and calling the getter-method.

Second Approach:

YAML:

```
countries: India, USA
```

Country.class

```
@Value("${countries}")
private List<String> countries;
```