# Read application variable (assoc array) form application.yml / java, spring

Tags: java, spring, environment-variables, yaml

I am working on a spring project where I need to read multiple account credentials (login and password) from application yml file.

I have written the credentials as an associative array like this (I don't know any better way to do it):

```
app:
  mail:
    accounts:
    - login: firstlogin
      password: firstpassword
    - login: secondlogin
      password: secondpassword
```

Then I mapped these values to spring application with `@Value` annotation:

```
@Service
public class MyClass {
 
  @Values("${app.mail.accounts}")
  private List<Map<String, String>> accounts;

   ...
}
```

But spring keep throwing an Exception because it fails to read these values.

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Could not resolve placeholder 'intelaw.mail.accounts' in value "${app.mail.accounts}"
```

Comment: hey, use `@ConfigurationProperties` instead of `@Value`

Comment: look similar discussion here with list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699385/spring-boot-yaml-configuration-for-a-list-of-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing your application.yml, you can tune your datastructures and make this work.

Create a class **Account**

```
class Account {
      private String login;
      private String password;

    //constructors, getters and setters here
}
```

and read it using a class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("app.mail")
class MyClass {
   private List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
   //getters and setters here
}
```

and in your service class, you can use it like :

```
@Autowired
private MyClass myClass;

void someMethod() {
  myClass.getAccounts();
}
```